# .NET C# App running good on Development PC but doesn't run on Production computer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013

So it's basically as stated in the title. I've created a WPF app in Visual Studio 2013 using some external libraries.

Application works flawlessly on my Development machine (Windows 8.1 x64 + Visual Studio 2013) but doesn't run at all on Production device (Tablet with Windows 8 (NOT 8.1)). App is developed under .NET 4.5, doesn't matter if I try to run Debug or Release version. The proccess just hangs a while and then closes without any errors or messages.

If anyone would know what to do or how to fix this I would be very happy.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: Is this a Store app or a desktop app?

Comment: @MingSlogar WPF is not available for Store apps.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen I wasn't sure if the OP knew this; many Store app developers think that since they're coding in XAML, it's WPF. If, in fact, it was a Store app, the crash could be caused by using different libraries between 8 and 8.1.

Comment: No, it's definately a WPF app ;)

Answer (score 3):

The first thing too look up in this situation, would be the Windows event log. When a .NET application crashes badly, the .NET Runtime will log an event there.
Most of the time, these events will log the stack trace which lead to the crash. This will give you a hint as to what happened.

Such logs are found in the "Application" category, and the source name you need to look for is ".NET Runtime". Usually, there will be another entry with the source name "Application Error", but this one is much less likely to help you.

Another useful technique, is to add a Console.WriteLine call at the start of your program, in order to see if that line gets to run at all.

Depending on what you find using these techniques, you may also want to use tools such as [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/), as suggested by Mike Dinescu.

Comment: Yes, I've used Dependency Walker and it showed that I'm missing "ieshims.dll", after a quick google search I've found that it's used in VC++ 2005 redistributable, installed it, but with no effect. Gonna look into the Event logs

Comment: Ok, I've checked and that's my error: http://pastebin.com/58trXNKC
The app is using local SQL files (.mdf) and I do have SQL Local installed but with no use.

Comment: @drajvver You got an XamlParseException. This error is not very helpful in itself, because it indicates that something went wrong during the time the WPF is initializing your Window. Usually, this will indicate that an error occured in the constructor for your window, but it can also occasionaly be caused by an error in a type initializer.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely a binding error occurs at start-up but the production machine you're testing on is configured to silently report these errors and it doesn't display the typical dialog box that would inform you that the process crashed.

Don't fret though, that message would probably not help you too much anyway.

What you need to do is inspect the main executable with a tool that can generate a dependency tree and figure out which DLLs are missing. Most likely these will be native binaries, not managed. The usual suspects are the VC runtime, or MFC or ATL libraries but there could be others too. That's why you need to use a tool such as [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or [RedGate's Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/) to find all dependencies for the main executable.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your external libraries are not compiled into final .exe file. So you either need to include them in the same folder or merge them into exe but this process can be quite tricky. Look for ILMerge. However it is way easier to just copy them with your exe file.

Comment: That's what I've already done and it's not that unfortunately.

Comment: Other than .dll files apps can also crash immediately after startup if .NET Framework 4.5 is not installed on target device...